# calling a method depending on options (best way to refactor)

Tags: ruby, refactoring

I have a function wherein I pass a string and an option to use it as regexp

```
def regexp_this?(string, arg1, arg2, regx = false)
  if regx
    method1 %r{#{string}:someconstantstring}
    method2 %r{#{string}:someconstantstring:#{arg1}}
    method3 %r{#{string}:someconstantstring:#{arg1}:anotherconstant:#{#arg2}}
  else
    method1 "#{string}:someconstantstring"
    method2 "#{string}:someconstantstring:#{arg1}"
    method3 "#{string}:someconstantstring:#{arg1}:anotherconstant:#{#arg2}"
  end
end
```

`method1`, `method2` and `method3` are calls to expire_fragment.  I'm building a cache based on the current state of the page.  If arg1 or arg2 is declared or not so I have different cache keys which I need to expire.

Is there a way to refactor this?

Comment: You need to tell what `method1`, `method2`, and `method3` do. You should also make it clear if `regex` is meant to be a boolean flag. It is extra work to guess that.

Comment: they're actually calls to expire_fragment.  i'm building a cache based on the current state of the page. if arg1 or arg2 is declared or not so i have different cache keys which I need to expire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the conditional, at least, you should be able to do something like this:

```
def regexp_this?(string, arg1, arg2, regx = false)
  # Select whether you want a String or Regexp parameter.
  argument_klass = (regx ? Regexp : String)

  method1 argument_klass.new("#{string}: ...")
  method2 argument_klass.new("#{string}: ...")
  method3 argument_klass.new("#{string}: ...")
end
```

Comment: I think you have your conditional backwards.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. Fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

you have multiple responsibilities for one method, separate them and name them appropriately.  You have a regex validation, multiple arguments, and multiple methods in a method.  I recommend reading [the SOLID principles](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdndevs/archive/2009/07/15/the-solid-principles-explained-with-motivational-posters.aspx).

Comment: lol why was this voted down.  I thought it was a good answer.